# Problems with Tango SDK Ikariotikos Version Sample in Asus Zen Fone AR

Tags: google-project-tango

I tested Tango SDK Ikariotikos Version on Asus Zen Fone AR.
AreaLearning After running the New Area Description in the Scene, the ADF was saved and switched back to AreaLearning Scene.
However, when you run the New Area Description again, you will get the error message

> "Failed to connect to Tango Service."

There is no problem with Phab2 pro.
Do you know this problem?
Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you running an example from the Github repo? Also, which SDK are you using? Java, C/C++, Unity? 

This sometimes happens when you don't handle the Tango service properly upon exiting the app or closing an activity, etc.

Comment: I am using the Tango Unity3d SDK.
The example uses AreaLearning.
Zenfone always "Failed to connect to Tango Service."